# Bootstrap 4 - "Transparent" fixed navbar but without letters see-through

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, transparent

I have a webpage with 2 diff colors backgrounds, like:

```
<body>
  <div class="bg1">aaa</div>
  <div class="bg2>bbb</div>
</body>
```

```
.bg1 {background: green; height: 100vh;}
.bg2 {background: red; height: 100vh;}
```

I want to add Bootstrap 4 fixed top navbar. I want this navbar to be the same color as div below it. It would looks like the navbar is "transparent", but without seen text "aaa" or "bbb" from divs.

I tried:

1. navbar background: transparent. The problem is that I see "aaa" and "bbb" from divs.
2. navbar background: inherit. The problem is that I can inherit only 1 parent background, but I want 2 diff backgrounds.
3. I can create the right background in 1 div using gradient. The problem is that "inherit" doesn't work with gradients.

I still have an option to change navbar color on scroll with js, but it's not perfect. In this case navbar will change color completely in one moment, there will not be effect of scrolling colors under "transparent" navbar. Hard to explain :(

Am I missing something?

Comment: I read a few, times and still fail to understand what you actually want to achieve. Is it text `aaa` `bbb` you need to hide their background or `div`'s themselves?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry my explanation is bad.
I want my navbar be the same color as divs. But I can’t use “transparent” because I don’t want to see “aaa” and “bbb” through the navbar.

Comment: have you tried `visibility: hidden` perhaps?

Comment: Hmmm, I can only think of making “aaa” and “bbb” texts invisible when they reach the area under navbar on scrolling. Sounds doable? Ahh, no, it will not work, since I can hide only entire element...

Comment: Here, I found the same problem with possible solution. Not yet able to make it work for me, though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975246/bootstrap-navbar-inherit-a-gradient-color-of-parent